# Modify prettyDate() to work with a string with another datetime format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm was playing with John Resig prettyDate function in order to put it to work with a string with this format:
`'2013-01-04 20:02:28'`
But so far I haven't been successful...this function is working with iso datetimes only..

```
function prettyDate(time){
    var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
        diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 )
        return;

    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && "just now" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago";
}
```

By default the result with my string is:

```
>prettyDate('2013-01-04 20:02:28')
>undefined
```

Please, could somebody help me to modify it to work with my format? Thanks.

PD:http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the format that isn't working, it's that the function `return`s when `day_diff >= 31`. As of right now `day_diff` will be 47 when the function is run.

Remove the check from the condition, and add a condition to the return portion that handles when `day_diff` is more than 31:

```
function prettyDate(time){
    var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
        diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 )
        return;

    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && "just now" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago" ||
        day_diff + " days ago";
}
```